# problem solving on work rate

Tags: problem-solving

please tell me this problem has insufficient data..

5 men and 2 boys working together can do four times as much work as a man and a boy. working capacities of a woman and a boy are in the ratio ... 
a. 1:2
b. 1:3
c. 2:1
d. 3:1

the solution given is..
Let 1 man's 1 day's work = x and 1 boy's 1 day's work = y
then, 
12x + 16y= 1/5
13x + 24y=1/4

Solving these two equations, 
we get x=1/100 and y=1/200
Required ratio= x:y --> 1/100:1/200 -->2:1

Comment: The word "woman" is mentioned ONCE in the entire question. So unless you tell us a little more about the role of women in this question, we regret to inform you that it lacks the data required to answer it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I just wanted to confirm my supposition that this problem has insufficient data. :)